# Hyperlink from a count query to extract associated data in access

Tags: hyperlink, odbc, expression, ms-access-2010, extract

I have a Count query that uses multiple criteria to produce a result looking like:

count ID

1 "abc"

4 "bcd"

5 "def"

1 "cde"

This shows how many times the ID appears in a given database.  The datasource is through an odbc connection that updates automatically.  So the ID values change everytime it is opened.  I would like to try to turn the unique ID or the associated count into a hyperlink that when clicked will return all information involved in the count (*note the database has much more information associated with the ID's than is counted, a date range of the previous three months is applied.) Can this be done simply?

Database format:
ID   Instance   Device   DateBeg    DateEnd

Thanks in advance,

LP

Comment: Any clues on how this could be achieved?  I believe my sticking point is referencing the hyperlink text value in the code.

Comment: I still have not found a way to achieve a list of associated values with the count.  I have also attempted programming a button to perform this query but I do not know how to make it work.  Thanks again,

Comment: I am still working on this issue and have not found a solution any input into how this could possibly be achieved would be greatly appreciated.  I believe it is a pretty nice challenge for someone in IT as our company IT has not come up with a solution either.

Answer (score 0):

The short version -

This should be simple to do using a report (but could also be done using a form I will be explaining how to do a report for this version). You would just make a report that includes all of your fields then call the report on click. It is important to mention that you will need to view the query via a form to make this work.

A more detailed version -

The first step will be to make a form based on your query (you will not be able to do this directly from a query). To do this select your query then click on the create tab then click Multiple Items Form. Adjust as needed.

Then create a report that shows ALL of the records how you want it to display. (I will call it rpt_ViewDetails) (we will limit later)

When you are done adjusting click on the field that contains the "abc" etc. results (if this is a calculated field it will be more complicated.) I will call this field "Criteria" for the example. Go to the events tab on the property sheet (in design view). use the On Dbl Click event and go to code builder.
This is what the code would look like (place in between the private sub.... and the end sub lines of code):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "frm_ViewDetails", acViewNormal, , "[Criteria] = " & Me.Critera
```

Let me know if you have any trouble with this, also let me know if the structure is different than I am assuming, I will need a more detailed report of what the query is doing if this is the case, what the structure of the database is etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try this soon and let you know how it works out!